# CryptoNight Algorithm Keccak1600?

Tags: cryptonight

I've looked at this file https://github.com/monero-project/monero/blob/master/src/crypto/slow-hash.c#L543

What does it mean when it says " CryptoNight Step 1:  Use Keccak1600 to initialize the 'state' (and 'text') buffers from the data. */?"

Answer (score 6):

The [Cryptonight description](https://cryptonote.org/cns/cns008.txt) by the Cryptonote team states that

> First, the input is hashed using Keccak [KECCAK] with parameters b = 1600 and c = 512.

In the primitive family [Keccak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-3), *b* is the width of bit block of the permutation function.

> Given an input bit string N, a padding function pad, **a permutation
>   function f that operates on bit blocks of width b**, a rate r and an
>   output length d, we have capacity c = b − r and the sponge
>   construction Z = spongef,pad,r, yielding a bit string Z of
>   length d, works as follows

This value of *b* is also used by SHA-3 for instance.

EDIT

Regarding your question about the location of the value 1600 in the code:

Function *[keccak1600](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/blob/5c2dfe157b48a486eb2b92dcf8789b3b1eb20f60/src/crypto/keccak.c#L121)* is defined as a special case of function *[keccak](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/blob/5c2dfe157b48a486eb2b92dcf8789b3b1eb20f60/src/crypto/keccak.c#L78)* with parameter *mdlen* equal to the size in bits of the type *state_t*. This type is an array of 25 uint64_t so the total size is 25*64=1600.

Comment: Sorry, I am new to programming, so I  put that where in this script? hash_process(&state.hs, data, length);

    memcpy(text, state.init, INIT_SIZE_BYTE);